# Redo nested loop if result is not what i wanted

Tags: php, nested-loops

I have eight soccerteams that plays 1x1 on four courts every weekend. 
What i want to accomplish is to randomly set the courts, but the courts aren´t allowed to ever be the same as the previous game for any of the teams.

I have a foreach loop for each round that is containing a foreach loop for each game in that round.

The problem is that i set the courts randomly, and in the last game of a round the single remaining court doens´t always work with the specified rules. So i need to retry the foreach loop for each match in the current round. How can i do that? Do i need to approach this differently?

**Here is an example of the second round of a season:**
The home teams previous court: 1
The away teams previous court: 2
Teams: 2 vs. 4
Court: 3

These courts are already in use: 3, 
The home teams previous court: 3
The away teams previous court: 1
Teams: 6 vs. 1
Court: 2

These courts are already in use: 3, 2, 
The home teams previous court: 4
The away teams previous court: 2
Teams: 8 vs. 3
Court: 1

These courts are already in use: 3, 2, 1, 
The home teams previous court: 4
The away teams previous court: 3
Teams: 7 vs. 5
Court: NO POSSIBLE ALTERNATIVES

Code example

```
$rounds = SQL FOR SELECTING ALL ROUNDS;

$teams = array();

$i = 0;
$prevround = '';

$reload = false;

foreach($rounds as $round) {

    $roundid = $round->ROUND;

    $matches = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ROUND = '$roundid'";

foreach($matches as $match) {
    $i++;


    $round = $match->ROUND;

    // If new round (could possibly be placed above foreach instead)
    if($round != $prevround) {
        echo "<h2>Round nr. ".$match->ROUND."</h2><br />";
        $courtarray = array();

        $prevround = $match->ROUND;
        $clearcache = false;
        $prevcourt = 0;
    }


    $stop = false;
    echo "These courts are already in use:";
    foreach($courtarray as $bannummer) {
        echo $bannummer.", ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    echo "The home teams previous court: ".$teams[$match->TEAM_HOME]."<br>";
    echo "The away teams previous court:".$teams[$match->TEAM_AWAY]."<br>";
    //for($j=1;$j<5;$j++) {
    $k = 0;
    back:
    $j = rand(1,4);
        //Check if the random number (1-4) can match the rules
        if($j == $teams[$match->TEAM_HOME] or $j == $teams[$match->TEAM_AWAY] or in_array($j, $courtarray)) {
            //Try this 10 times
            $k++;
            if($k > 10) {
                $reload = true;
            } else {
                // Yes, i know this is not a nerdy way to do it :)
                goto back; 
            }

        } else if($stop != true) {
            $court = $j;
            $bcourtarray[] = $court;
            $stop = true;
        }
    //}



    echo "<strong>Teams: ".$match->TEAM_HOME." - ".$match->TEAM_AWAY."<br />";

    if($court == $prevcourt) {
        echo "Court: NO POSSIBLE ALTERNATIVES</strong><br />";
        $startover = true;
    } else {
        echo "Court: ".$court."</strong><br />";
    }

    // Used to save the different team´s previous court
    $teams[$match->TEAM_HOME] = $court;
    $teams[$match->TEAM_AWAY] = $court;

    $prevcourt = $court;

}
```

}

So i guess i need to make

```
 $matches = $db2->get_results("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ROUND = '$roundid'");

 foreach($matches as $match) {
```

to run again with the current $roundid; if the script fails to find a last court to use.

Or is there a smarter solution to this? Should i make a function that calls the loop instead? Can i call that within itself?

Sometimes you get stuck in a certain way of thinking. :)

Comment: I think you can solve your question with a recursive function, but I can't figure out what you mean exactly by all the courts and such... It is not clear to me what you want to end up with...

Comment: @RichardBernards he basically wants to match all teams to play against each other randomly. But they must not match against the team they played before. So if Team 1 has played against Team 4, every Match is fine but Team 4 again.

Comment: How the teams play against each other is predefined. What i want to do is to randomly set the court/field on which they play so that no team plays on the same field as they did their last game.

Maybe i have misused the word court, i mean like "football field". English is not my native language, obviously :)

Comment: @RichardBernards A recursive function seems to be what i need. Thanks! Post it as a answer and i´ll accept it if you´d like! :)

Comment: It wasn't a recursive function you needed after all... Look at my new answer. If I'm right, this should work by copy-pasting it into your code...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. No need for a recursive function. At the bottom you can find links to the PHP references for the important functions used.
What I am doing, is keeping track of courts used per team (in `$usedCourts[__TEAM__]`) and look if there are any courts (`$courts`) which have not been occuppied by both teams using `array_diff()`. I select the first available court by using `array_shift()`:

```
$numberOfCourts = 3;





$courts = range(1,$numberOfCourts);
$usedCourts = array();

foreach($matches as $match) {
    if(!array_key_exists($match->TEAM_HOME, $usedCourts)) {
        $usedCourts[$match->TEAM_HOME] = array();
    }
    if(!array_key_exists($match->TEAM_AWAY, $usedCourts)) {
        $usedCourts[$match->TEAM_AWAY] = array();
    }
    $possibleCourts = array_diff($courts, $usedCourts[$match->TEAM_HOME], $usedCourts[$match->TEAM_AWAY]);
    echo $match->TEAM_HOME . ' - ' . $match->TEAM_AWAY;
    if(count($possibleCourts)) {
        $currentCourt = array_shift($possibleCourts);
        $usedCourts[$match->TEAM_HOME][] = $currentCourt;
        $usedCourts[$match->TEAM_AWAY][] = $currentCourt;
        echo ' on court: ' . $currentCourt;
    } else {
        echo ' has no available field';
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

- [`range()` - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)
- [`array_diff()` - Manual](http://php.net/array_diff)
- [`array_key_exists()` - Manual](http://php.net/array_key_exists)
- [`array_shift()` - Manual](http://php.net/array_shift)

Comment: Every game gets field 1 from your example. Even if it would work wouldn´t it produce the same result as my loop, that the last field available is not possible for the last remaining teams because they used it last time?

Comment: Thanks for taking time btw!